# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have a project on `spring boot` + `spring data` + `hibernate`. I have a bean of `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean` witch is implemented `org.springframework.validation.Validator`. So I needed to include in the project `webMvc` and I used annotation `@EnableWebMvc` and extened my configuration from `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. But `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` provided it's own implementation of `org.springframework.validation.Validator` so I marked my bean with `@Primary`, but it doesn't help.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


  @Override
  public Validator getValidator() {
    return myValidationBean();
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public LocalValidatorFactoryBean myValidationBean() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: mvcValidator, myValidationBean
```

Full stackTrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: mvcValidator,myValidationBean  

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:160)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.myProject.ApiControllerTest.getEmployees_byUserId(ApiControllerTest.java:339)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: mvcValidator,myValidationBean   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver$1.getTarget(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.forExecutables(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.myProject.ApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$24c340c2.getEmployees(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
```

Comment: You should **not** use EnableWebMvc in Spring Boot. That disables all the spring boot autoconfiguration of MVC. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration. You don't need to define any bean for validation. As son as you have hibernate validator in the classpath, boot creates it for you. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-validation

Comment: I used it for easiest way of configuring `CORS`. `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` provided method `addCorsMappings` witch I used in my configuration

Comment: So, define a WebMvcConfigurer, but don't use EnableWebMvc. Once again, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors. You're missing a lot of stuff, and lose a lot of time by not reading the documentation. Read it.

Comment: change the signature for the validator bean to ValidatorFactory instead of  LocalValidatorFactoryBean  and remove the overridden getValidator method then  recheck please

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you for your answers, they really helps, but From docs: 
`@Configuration` with the `@EnableWebMvc`  leaves all `MVC` configuration in your hands.`
And I cannot understand why an exception occurs. I have provided my own bean with `@Primary` annotation. Why this annotation was ignored?

Comment: @MohammadRezaAlagheband of cause it helps, because `ValidatorFactory` is interface and it does not extends `org.springframework.validation.Validator`

Comment: the problem arise when you have mixed defining a an independent validator bean (myValidationBean) with the one that is the result of overriding  getValidator: you have got two options - either use @ springbootapplication and provide your custom bean definition or in case of extending webMvcConfigurerAdapter , override getValidator (with @ Bean above it)  and return created instance inside that method (in your example myValidationBean would not have the effect as you add overridden getValidator ). in this way you will avoid confusion.  if that helps let me know to post the complete answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not use EnableWebMvc in Spring Boot. That disables all the spring boot autoconfiguration of MVC. Define a WebMvcConfigurer, but don't use EnableWebMvc.